# file_get_contents() converts - to gibberish

Tags: php, unicode

I'm trying to use PHP function `file_get_contents()` on this url: `http://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt0460681` which should return a JSON object. 
The Year returns as `2005â€` when its suppose to return as `2005-`, which I find really random.

I have tried to convert the encoding of my document betweem UTF8 and ASCII to see if it was simply outputted wrong, but this has had no effect.

Comment: `–` and `-` are two different characters. So, the problem is with the API not with PHP. Because, it's sending you the invalid first character `–` instead of the second

Comment: is there any way I can convert it into a `-` or something else usefull?

Comment: the lamest would be to use `$content = str_replace('â€', '-', $content)`;

Comment: For some odd reason, that does not work. Still shows as `â€`

Comment: make sure the are no other chars or empty spaces.

Comment: Did you try print json_encode(json_decode(file_get_contents($url),true)); ?

Comment: Seems that you page in ISO-1251 encoding. Change it to UTF-8 in meta tag: <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API works correctly, it sends a header specifying the encoding of the JSON data:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

But `file_get_contents()` doesn't relay that information. [PHP just assumes all data uses some 8-bit character encoding](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). So the returned string will just contain the sequence of UTF-8 encoded **bytes** returned by the server.

Since PHP throws away the encoding information, you have to make an assumption here: it's probably safe to assume the API always uses UTF-8 to encode the text:

- Option 1 (the one I would recommend): change the encoding for your HTML output to UTF-8. You should then change your web server settings so it specifies that encoding in the Content-Type header. `echo $content` will then give the expected result. But it requires you change the rest of your PHP code to output proper UTF-8.
- Option 2: use the `htmlentities` function to convert the characters to entities. Try this: `htmlentities($content, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "utf-8")`

If you don't know for sure what encoding the API will use, you'll have to use a module like curl, which allows you to inspect the response headers sent by the API.

Answer (score 1):

`-` and `–` are two different characters. 
The first one is know as `en dash` whereas the second is called `hyphen-minus`.

Here is glyph, unicode, htmlentity and name of the two.

```
– | U+2013  | &#8211; | hyphen-minus
- | U+002D  | &#45;   | en dash
```

So, the problem is with the API not sending the proper value with proper encoding. Because, it's sending you the invalid first character `–` instead of the second  one.

A quick solution for this would be to convert the string manually as

```
$content = str_replace('â€', '-', $content);
```

Comment: The API works fine. It sends the JSON string encoded in UTF-8, and properly indicates that in the response headers. The thing which is broken here is PHP, as it still assumes all text is using an 8-bit character set.

Answer (score 1):

You could try converting the string to uft8 directly in the php code using

```
uft8_decode($string)
```

and

```
uft8_encode($string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to sanitize the field content, removing all non-numeric chars. For example:

```
$year = preg_replace("/\\D/i", '', $responseObject['Year']);
```